# Mage_Ajaxsddto_Helper_Data' not found in app\Mage.php on line 547

Tags: magento-1.9

unable to open permissions_role page I get below error

> -Class 'Mage_Ajaxsddto_Helper_Data' not found in E:\CUBE9-XAMPP\htdocs\boxed\app\Mage.php on line 547

already added below code
4/ Add it on the  node like this:

```
<helpers>
    <ajaxsddto>
        <class>Vendor_Ajaxsddto_Helper</class>
    </ajaxsddto>
</helpers>
```

5/ Create folder **app/code/{community/local}/{Vendor}/Ajaxsddto/Helper** folder if it doesn't exists and create file Data.php:

```
class Vendor_Ajaxsddto_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

any other resolution.

config.xml file

0.1.0
        
    
    
        
            
                standard
                
                    Etheme_Ajaxaddto
                    ajax
                
            
            
                
                    
                
            
        
        
            
                
                    ajaxaddto.xml

```
<global>
    <models>
        <ajax>
            <class>Etheme_Ajaxaddto_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>ajax_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </ajax>
        <ajax_mysql4>
            <class>Etheme_Ajaxaddto_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <ajax>
                    <table>ajax</table>
                </ajax>
            </entities>
        </ajax_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <ajax_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Etheme_Ajaxaddto</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </ajax_setup>
        <ajax_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </ajax_write>
        <ajax_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </ajax_read>
    </resources>
    <blocks>
        <ajax>
            <class>Etheme_Ajaxaddto_Block</class>
        </ajax>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <ajaxaddto>
            <class>Etheme_Ajaxaddto_Helper</class>
        </ajaxaddto>
    </helpers>
    <events>
        <controller_action_postdispatch>
            <observers>
                <etheme_ajaxaddto_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Etheme_Ajaxaddto_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>getListproduct</method>
                </etheme_ajaxaddto_observer>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch>
    </events>
</global>
```

Comment: Can you please add code of your `config.xml`

Answer (score 2):

**1/** Search recursively for the word `Ajaxsddto` inside folders `app/code/community/` and `app/code/local/`

**2/** When you find the module, open his `config.xml` inside `app/code/{community/local}/{Vendor}/Ajaxsddto/etc` folder

**3/** Search for the string `<helpers>`, normally you won't find it.

**4/** Add it on the `<global>` node like this:

```
<helpers>
    <ajax>
        <class>Etheme_Ajaxaddto_Helper</class>
    </ajax>
</helpers>
```

**5/** Create folder `app/code/{community/local}/Etheme/Ajaxaddto/Helper` folder if it doesn't exists and create file `Data.php`:

```
class Etheme_Ajaxaddto_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

**6/** Flush your Magento cache and test again.

Comment: after defining helper in config.xml you also have to add helper file (Data.php) in helper folder.

Comment: already add <helpers>
    <ajaxsddto>
        <class>Vendor_Ajaxsddto_Helper</class>
    </ajaxsddto>
</helpers>

Comment: I've updated point **4**, don't forget to clear your Magento cache.

Comment: Is this solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a typo mistake in your code. 
Search for keyword `ajaxsddto` in your files and replace it with `ajaxaddto`. I cant say which file contains the error so You need to search in all your files for this wrong keyword.
There is no helper defined with name `ajaxsddto` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure that you haven't disabled compilation (System -> Tools -> Compilation) before installing the extension. Looks like you have cleared cache and Magento took extension configuration files but does not see the php files.

If compilation is enabled, you need to recompile the source files by pressing the corresponding button on this page.